# c++ Data serialization from templated class

Tags: c++, c++11, serialization, deserialization

I have a situation where I want to define a templated class which is able to get several different base types, like `int`, `char array`, `data structure` or a `string`. I want then to serialize and transmit the data using a method which accepts a pointer to array of chars and a length parameters.

```
sendData(const void *, size_t);

template <typename T>
T myClass(T data)
{
   // cast data to char array; calculate the length if not given
   sendData(data, length);
}
```

What is the best way to cast the the data parameter and calculate the size? Is template specialization the best option to deal with a case where we only expect to have predefined list of data types for the template? I am looking for a solution using native C++ and no external serialization libraries, and also avoiding `reinterpret_cast`. Can anyone provide me basic implementation example?

And on the receiver side, is there a way how the receiver can determine and validate that the data received have the expected type, before doing the deserialization?

Comment: You can't do that with a `std::string` or any other data that has internal allocation of memory. You also can't rely on the data having the same memory layout on different machines/systems/compilers.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using std::ostringstream.

```cpp
#include <sstream>

template <typename T>
void myClassImpl(const T& data)
{
   std::ostringstream oss; 
   oss << data;
   sendData(oss.str());
}
```

Note: length can be retrieved from std::string

**Edit:**
If you only want this to work for specific types than you can overload the my myClass function and have the same implementation using templates. See the example below.

```cpp
void myClass(int data)
{
   myClassImpl(data);
}
```

Note: from C++17 you can also use [variants](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Comment: The function should work only with few specific data types, like int, array of chars or ints, a string. For other (unsupported) types it should return error.

Comment: Edited answer accordingly